# Swap style sheets for mobile device

Tags: css, mobile

So I've been trying to get my site to load a seperate style sheet for mobile devices. I've tried all the media query ways, and the two test devices I have (Samsung Note 2 and iPad 2) both ignore them.

I found this script here which pops up an alert for mobile devices, and it works brilliantly. So I was wondering if it would be possible to use this script to swap one style sheet for another?

```
     <script>
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/))  || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/))) {
   alert("we've got an iDevice, Scotty");
}

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/)) {
   load("Droid me baby");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043983/how-to-make-style-sheet-for-tablet-and-iphone

I've read that some developers were looking at request headers to detect what browser the device was making a request from. Using that and the min/max dimensions of the screen they were able to infer the device being used. An online hotel booking website was showing more expensive search results for customers using iPhone, iPad, and MAC web browsers. heh.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried, those devices should be able to handle media queries

Comment: The devices can handle the media queries just fine, but resolution based queries are useless since most devices now are coming with high res screens.

I also tried using the "handheld" media query, but it didn't seem to do a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool to use is Respond.js.  I use it on my site with `@media` queries with no issues at all, even for Internet Explorer.

- The Galaxy Note 2 uses Android, which is compatible with CSS media
  queries.
- The iPad 2 uses iOS Safari, also compatible with media queries.

**[Reference for browser compatibilities](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)**

**[Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)**

**[Very good article on responsive design that explains media query use well.](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)**

And on the note of non-responsive, non-media query - this is a great tool to see what the user's browser can/cant do:

**[Browscap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap)**

Comment: The problem with the media queries is that I'd have to do a whole bunch of them based on device, orientation and screen size to optimize it all. INstead if I just concentrate on mobile vs screen, I can gamble that most people use their mobile devices in portrait mode, and have the style sheet handle that directly. I suppose if I could have gotten the aspect media query to work properly that would have solved it too.